# Reading multiple nextint

Tags: java

The scanner stops reading the integers after the first one from the scanner class. How do I make it read them all, even if there are spaces?

```
System.out.println("please enter numbers to decrypt"); 
num = sc.nextInt();  // number to decrypt
result = sourcetext.charAt(num); //retrives each character that num points it to from sourcetext
int i=0;
for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    temp= sourcetext.charAt(sourcetext.indexOf(i));
}
System.out.println(sourcetext.charAt(sourcetext.indexOf(i)));
```

Comment: Call `nextInt` in a loop.

Comment: when I put nextInt inside the loop it says that num is not initialised anymore  int i=0;
 
        for (i = 0; i< 0; i++)
        num = sc.nextInt();                // number to decrypt
        result = sourcetext.charAt(num);
        temp = sourcetext.charAt(num);
        System.out.println(temp);

Comment: Can you instead update the question by editing? Code is not really readable in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to allow the user to enter multiple numbers separated by spaces, then you need to use scanner.nextLine() instead.

```
String inputNumbers = scanner.nextLine();
String[] numbers = inputNumbers.split(" ");
for (number : numbers) [
  // handle numbers
}
```